# Why "Joined" does not draw all the lines?

Tags: plotting

I'm working on a project in order to plot a graphical method for finite-difference equations called [cobweb method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobweb_plot). The next figure was succesful try for

$$x_{t+1} = Rx_t - \frac{R}{2000}x_t^2$$

[image]

But, when I try with

$$x_{t+1} = \cos{x_t},$$

and copy-paste the code I used before, the result was

[image]

For some reason `Joined->True` doesn't draw all the lines. Changing a litle bit the number of point plotted, from 17 to 16, the figure is correct

[image]

---

There is a problem, but, where? My code is the following

```
difEqu[x_] := N[Cos[x]]

traFin = {{0.4,0},{0.4,0.921061},{0.921061,0.921061},{0.921061,0.604976},
 {0.604976,0.604976},{0.604976,0.822516},{0.822516,0.822516},{0.822516,0.68038},
 {0.68038,0.68038},{0.68038,0.777334},{0.777334,0.777334},{0.777334,0.712786},
 {0.712786,0.712786},{0.712786,0.756543},{0.756543,0.756543},{0.756543,0.727213},
 {0.727213,0.727213},{0.727213,0.74703},{0.74703,0.74703},{0.74703,0.73371},
 {0.73371,0.73371},{0.73371,0.742695},{0.742695,0.742695},{0.742695,0.736649},
 {0.736649,0.736649},{0.736649,0.740724},{0.740724,0.740724},{0.740724,0.73798},
 {0.73798,0.73798},{0.73798,0.739829},{0.739829,0.739829},{0.739829,0.738584}}

extremos = {{0.4,0},{0.739829,0.738584}}

Show[
 Plot[
  Evaluate[
   {Legended[Style[difEqu[x], RGBColor[0., 0., 1.], Thickness[0.004]],"x[0] = 0.6"],
   Legended[Style[x, RGBColor[0., 0., 0.], Thickness[0.004], Dashed],"Identidad"]}
  ],
 {x, 0, 1},
 PlotTheme -> "Scientific",
 ImageSize -> Large,
 PlotRange -> Full,
 FrameLabel ->
  {Style["x (t)", FontSize -> 35],
  Style["x (t+1)", FontSize -> 35]},
  LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial", 20, RGBColor[0., 0., 0.]}
 ],
 ListPlot[
  {traFin, extremos},
  PlotStyle -> {{RGBColor[1., 0., 0.],Thickness[0.001]},{RGBColor[1., 0., 0.]}},
  Joined -> {True, False}
 ]
]
```

I get traFin with another code. The number of iterations here is 16, i.e.

$$x_{16+1} = \underbrace{x(x(\cdots(}_{\text{16 times}}0.4) = 0.738584.$$

---

**Edit:** The following code corresponds to 17 iterations:

```
difEqu[x_] := N[Cos[x]]

traFin = {{0.4,0},{0.4,0.921061},{0.921061,0.921061},{0.921061,0.604976},{0.604976,0.604976},{0.604976,0.822516},{0.822516,0.822516},{0.822516,0.68038},{0.68038,0.68038},{0.68038,0.777334},{0.777334,0.777334},{0.777334,0.712786},{0.712786,0.712786},{0.712786,0.756543},{0.756543,0.756543},{0.756543,0.727213},{0.727213,0.727213},{0.727213,0.74703},{0.74703,0.74703},{0.74703,0.73371},{0.73371,0.73371},    {0.73371,0.742695},{0.742695,0.742695},{0.742695,0.736649},        {0.736649,0.736649},{0.736649,0.740724},{0.740724,0.740724},{0.740724,0.73798},{0.73798,0.73798},{0.73798,0.739829},{0.739829,0.739829},{0.739829,0.738584},{0.738584,0.738584},{0.738584,0.739423}}

extremos = {{0.4,0},{0.739829,0.738584}}

Show[
 Plot[
  Evaluate[
   {Legended[Style[difEqu[x], RGBColor[0., 0., 1.], Thickness[0.004]],"x[0] = 0.6"],
   Legended[Style[x, RGBColor[0., 0., 0.], Thickness[0.004], Dashed],"Identidad"]}
  ],
 {x, 0, 1},
 PlotTheme -> "Scientific",
 ImageSize -> Large,
 PlotRange -> Full,
 FrameLabel ->
  {Style["x (t)", FontSize -> 35],
  Style["x (t+1)", FontSize -> 35]},
  LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial", 20, RGBColor[0., 0., 0.]}
 ],
 ListPlot[
  {traFin, extremos},
  PlotStyle -> {{RGBColor[1., 0., 0.],Thickness[0.001]},{RGBColor[1., 0., 0.]}},
  Joined -> {True, False}
 ]
]
```

Comment: Unable to reproduce with the code above. The plot looks fine.

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi Yes, the code above corresponds to 16 iterations. I'll edit the post in order to include the code with the error, 17 iterations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you are running into is that the `ListPlot` is cropping the plot-region in an unlucky way. Put `PlotRange->All` as final option into the `ListPlot` call and you should be fine.

You could have found this issue yourself by inspecting the plots separately.